# d3 ticks have different widths

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to get all of my ticks to have the same width.  As of now some are twice as wide as you can see from the picture below.  Specifically, look at the difference between the tick for 06/07 and 06/09.

[image: chart with different width ticks]

I have tried setting `stroke-width: 1` and `shape-rendering: crispEdges` (and even `shape-rendering: auto`).  I've even looked at the way I define the x scale and x axis:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([startDate, endDate])
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d'))
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(1);
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

For what it's worth, the effect is consistent upon refreshes.  That is, 06/07's tick is always thicker than 06/09's.

Comment: I am assuming you have also tried `shape-rendering: geometricPrecision`?

Comment: Things got better after I added a y-axis and even better when I changed `crispEdges` to `geometricPrecision` but I think that `geometricPrecision` looks the same as auto.  'seems like as long as I don't use crispEdges.. which strikes me as odd since it's what Bostock uses all over the place.  Hmm.